# In elasticsearch if am searching for "smart watches" first it should show exact match then smart and then watch after that fuziness should

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used this query but the data is showing wrong

```
`{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "name": "smart watches"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "smart watches",
                        "fields": [
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "size": 10
}`
```

Outpur should be like below

- smart watches
- smart
- watches
- watch
- watchs
- wat

Comment: What is the output like right now? Please share that also.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, however, your query needs to look as shown below. You want to match all documents containing `smart` or `watches` (with some fuzziness) and that's what the `multi_match` does in the `must` part does. Then if you want to give a boost to the exact phrase match `smart watches`, you need to include it in a should clause.

What this query does is basically: return all docs containing `smart` or `watches` with some fuzziness, but give a boost to the documents that match `smart watches` exactly.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "smart watches",
            "fields": [
              "name"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name": "smart watches"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

The results are exactly as you lined out in your question, except for `wat` which cannot be matched unless you include some n-gram analysis.

Results:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "70i6O4sByYFGUCq223Nt",
    "_score" : 3.1871638,
    "_source" : {
      "text" : "smart watches"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "wmm6O4sBaXbCo6wO5dgq",
    "_score" : 1.093527,
    "_source" : {
      "text" : "smart"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "xdu6O4sBNsxIi3Ml-I2L",
    "_score" : 1.093527,
    "_source" : {
      "text" : "watches"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "hfK7O4sBxLlgI27VBZoO",
    "_score" : 0.9112724,
    "_source" : {
      "text" : "watchs"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "xtu6O4sBNsxIi3Ml_42y",
    "_score" : 0.6561161,
    "_source" : {
      "text" : "watch"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Still, this is showing the result of **watches** at the last

`{
    smart watches
    smart
    watch
    watchs
    **watches**
} `

Comment: @MohanT I've updated with the results I get, you can see that watches is not the last result but the third one, which conforms to what you expect.

Comment: when I am giving the count of 50 its showing like the one which i have sent

Comment: Of course it depends on the other documents you have, because the ranking is done by BM25 / TF-IDF and the order heavily depends on the frequency of terms you have in your index. If you can share your document set via gist, I can have a look at how to improve the ranking.